# Primefaces , jquery issue on including page with ui:include in p:tabview

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I had build a JSF 2.1.2 page with various primefaces components like p: calendar, p: selectOneMenu ...
This page works fine.
But :
I need to integrate this first page in an other page in a p:tab element with p: TabView parent :
like this:

```
<p:tabView id="tabview">
 <p:tab title="User admin">
  <ui:include src="firstPage.xhtml" />
 </p:tab>
</p:TabView>
```

Problem: primefaces components no longer works (no display with p:calendar for exemple) , I get many errors with firebug like jQuery is absent :

```
$(this.jqId + " ul").sortable is not a function
[Stopper sur une erreur]    

...d+" .ui-picklist-target-controls .ui-picklist-button-move-up").click(function(){...

primef...mefaces (ligne 27)
$(this.jqId + " ul").sortable is not a function
[Stopper sur une erreur]    

...d+" .ui-picklist-target-controls .ui-picklist-button-move-up").click(function(){...

.....
```

Thanks for your help.
Christophe.

Comment: say , if you change it into src="/firstPage.xhtml" (added "/") ...? also... i guess </p:TabView> is a typo ? capital "T"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your HTML output is syntactically valid. If the `firstPage.xhtml` represents a complete `<html>` page, then this will fail when you use it as an include file in another `<html>` page because nesting `<html><head><body>` tags is illegal.

You need to remove all `<html><head><body>` tags from `firstPage.xhtml` that way so that it really represents the sole tab content. E.g.

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
    <p>This is the tab content.</p>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Hi @BalusC I have a Bean initialization problem when I include Faceslet in Tab. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088522/ can you please look into it?