# How to lazy Load ManagedBean associated with included page in p:Tab, Only when Tab is opened

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:tabView` or `p:accordionPanel` and Facelets included in each `p:tab` using `ui:include`.
My Problem is ManagedBeans associated with each included page are Initialized on starting itself, How can I make them Initialize only when the particular Tab is opened.
Here is the code Sample:
index.xhtml

```
<p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="true">
   <p:tab title="Bean 1 Page 1">
    <ui:include src="page1.xhtml"/>
   </p:tab>

   <p:tab title="Bean 2 Page 2">
    <ui:include src="page2.xhtml"/>
   </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

page1.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{bean1.bean1PreRender}" type="preRenderView"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{bean1.bean1Text}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Bean1.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean1 implements Serializable{
    private String bean1Text = "Hello From Bean 1";
    public Bean1() {
        System.out.println("Bean 1 Constructor");
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Bean 1 @PostConstruct");
    }
    public void bean1PreRender(){
            System.out.println("Bean 1 PreRender PostBack Call");
        if(!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()){
            System.out.println("Bean 1 PreRender NON PostBack Call");
        }
    }
    //SETTER GETTER
}
```

page2.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{bean2.bean2PreRender}" type="preRenderView"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{bean2.bean2Text}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Bean2.java

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class Bean2 implements Serializable{
        private String bean2Text = "Hello From Bean 2";
        public Bean2() {
            System.out.println("Bean 2 Constructor");
        }
        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            System.out.println("Bean 2 @PostConstruct");
        }
        public void bean2PreRender(){
                System.out.println("Bean 2 PreRender PostBack Call");
            if(!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()){
                System.out.println("Bean 2 PreRender NON PostBack Call");
            }
        }
        //SETTER GETTER
    }

}
```

In the above example `#{bean1}` and `#{bean2}` are initialized on loading `index.xhtml` itself.
Default tab opened is Tab1 so it is obvious that `#{bean1}` is loaded but why `#{bean2}` ??
The main reason I'm posting this question is to transfer the data between Tabs, So if there is any alternative way is there then please suggest me.

*Using : Primfaces 3.5 and JSF 2.*1

Comment: Have you tried `<p:tabView dynamic="true">` ?

Comment: @RongNK: Yes but it ain't working, #{bean1} and #{bean2} are initialized on starting itself.

Comment: I think you should use commandButton alter for tabView.

Comment: I have to use TabView or AccorsionPanel.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the tab contenet to be lazily loaded, why not follow the pattern that is at least provided in the [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/accordionPanelDynamic.jsf) (the same applies to [`<p:tabView>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewDynamic.jsf))? To repeat that example (note `dynamic="true"` attribute):

```
<h:form>  
    <p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" cache="true">  
        <p:tab title="Bean 1 Page 1">
            <ui:include src="page1.xhtml"/>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Bean 2 Page 2">
            <ui:include src="page2.xhtml"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>
```

As to the reason, when JSF component tree is being built, all the included page content end up in that tree, so the corresponding beans are initialized. The same will happen in e.g.:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="false">
    <ui:include src="page1.xhtml"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

In the above code the content **will be included in JSF component tree** (view build time), but **will not be included in HTML DOM tree** (view render time) despite the fact that the panel group will never be rendered, as view is being built (`<ui:include>` taghandler) at a lifecycle event prior to when it is being rendered (`rendered` attribute). Likewise, the following snippet yields the desired effect, as both `<c:if>` and `<ui:include>` are taghandlers:

```
<c:if test="#{bean.tab eq 1}">
    <ui:include src="page1.xhtml"/>
</c:if>
```

---

Ultimalely, if PrimeFaces `<p:accordionPanel>` decides what to render at view render time, view build time tags will be evaluated as well (which is your case), so you can force the evaluation of taghandlers to happen only when the tab is changed by including a small `<c:if>` test. The kickoff example:

```
<h:form>  
    <p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" cache="true">
        <p:tab title="Bean 1 Page 1">
            <c:if test="#{component.parent.activeIndex eq 0 or empty component.parent.activeIndex}">
                <ui:include src="page1.xhtml"/>
            </c:if>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Bean 2 Page 2">
            <c:if test="#{component.parent.activeIndex eq 1}">
                <ui:include src="page2.xhtml"/>
            </c:if>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Hi skuntel thanks for the answer I'm using `dynamic="true" cache="true"` but no luck(see the updated code). I'll try with `<h:panelGroup>` and let you know

Comment: Hi skuntel, It didn't work  when I use `<h:panelGroup>` or `<c:if>`

Comment: @KishorP Panel group will never work, and JSTL's if works as expected. A tested example included. By the way, a good question. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks skuntsel, But I have one more question(I think I should post it ans new question), In my example I ain't keeping TabView/acctordionpanel in Form. Let's say I put it in form and include a another page which has form so now I'll have nest]ed forms, doesn't it violate the JSF rules or have any side effects?

Comment: I think that `<p:accordionPanel>` works without being enclosed in a `<h:form>`, so you can use separate forms in your included files.

Comment: No If you remove `<h:form>` around the `<p:accordionPanel>` `#{component.parent.activeIndex}` won't update.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense. Component model doesn't have any relationship to forms. Besides, omitting the form around the accordion panel doesn't change its working ability (at least in my test case).

Comment: Are all the tabs contents(page1.xhtml and page2.xhtml) are rendering in you example after removing form around accordion panel? which version of Primefaces you are using?

Comment: PF 3.5, yes, both tabs are loaded as they should even without a form.